# Registering an iOS extension to a URL scheme

Tags: ios, url-scheme, ios-extensions

I don't think this is possible but I've not been able to find anything conclusive.

Ideally I would like to register my Action Extension to be launched by a specific scheme - instead of my main application. I want this because of the benefit of being able to return to the previous application after completion.

Thanks.

[image: Action Extension plist]

[image: Main Application plist (including URL Schemes Array)]

Answer (score 1):

As i understand your question, you want to accept specific schemes in your application but want only extension to be configured to it.

Well this is fairly possible. You can create extension for your application and add URL schemes to the extension only. Remove specific URL schemes from your apps plist and add it to the extensions plist.

[image]

Comment: I've not tried this yet and was kinda hoping it would work like this. Wasn't sure what the alternative path to then receiving the URL if application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions isn't called

Comment: Registering the URL schemes in the extension's info.plist unfortunately doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Ah okay, I think see the misunderstanding. I current do have my extension configured to have the NSExtentionActivationRule of NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount - which is working correctly. This does allow my Action Extension to launch from the share sheet, but if instead the user clicks the URL with the scheme (inside of Safari, for example) it will instead launch my main application. That's the behaviour I'm trying to change. Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: Does you have that scheme configured in main app as well?

Comment: No, when I tested it I removed the schemes from the main application's plist

Comment: I am too struggling with the same issue while for same url type configured in both application extension, i will have 2 "Open In" visible in safari one of my App and other of my extension. I think there is no way to stop it but what i did was removed the support from my main app and then only extension one was visible from "Open In". Any specific format you are trying from open formats. Please post both plist code here.

Comment: That's interesting that you're getting an Open In option. For me it will either launch the main application (if I register in both) or say Safari cannot open this link (if I just register my extension. I'll post a couple screenshots in the original post.

Comment: Yeah still visible there. I'm thinking this isn't supported. Would require my extension to have it's own AppDelegate to handle the URL.